# sync framework on backup/restore scenarios

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, microsoft-sync-framework

I am syncing SQL Server databases using Microsoft Sync Framework.

My databases are frequently restored to earlier versions, and I need to keep the father (destination of sync process), updated.

Now, the thing is that I have a child A, with a table T1, and a father B with a table T1.

Both T1 tables have a table that "record" the operations, called T1_tracking. First, I sync T1, from A to B. Then, I restore the database in A to a earlier version, and generate again the data stored in T1 (with different information). Consequently T1_tracking in A are totally diferent of T1_tracking in B, and the Sync Framework tell me that it not have nothing to do.

Any solution? Please... Thanks!!...

Answer (score 0):

you need to run PerformPostRestoreFixup after you restore the database and before you sync it.

the scopes has a replicaid that identifies each replica. if you restore a db, you will have two scopes having the same id which will result to data not being synched.

to illustrate, let's say T1 was synched to A, and A records that the last time it synched with T1 has a timestamp of 1000.

you then restore A to an older version which of course has  lesser timestamp values. the you update the data on the restored db, but the timestamp only goes up to let's say 700.

when you sync it to T1, T1 says give me the changes that has timestamp greater than 1000 (the timestamp it recorded on last sync). so no changes is detected.

Sync FX does incremental sync, e.g., what has changed since last sync. it doesn't go comparing row by row to check the differences between tables.

by running PerformPostRestoreFixup, you're giving the restored copy a new replicaid. The old replicaid is still tracked in T1, so it knows it has already synched the existing data in the restored db. however, new changes will be reflected in the new replicaid, so when it syncs, T1 doesnt know about it  (it doesnt have any timestamp record on when it last synched with the new replicaid) and thus will be able to detect changes to sync.

P.S., this is a simplified illustration of your scenario, there's more to that that happens under the hood.